# I want to combine two rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `memberaccount` in which 1 stands for male and 2 for female.

I want to count the number of male and female using 'case'

```
Select 
    Male = (Case When gender_id = 1 Then Count(gender_id) Else 0 End),
    Female = (Case When gender_id = 2 Then Count(gender_id) Else 0 End)
From 
    MemberAccount
Group By
    gender_id
```

Result:

```
Male    Female
--------------
247     0
0       303
```

But I want result:

```
Male     Female
----------------
247      303
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Select 
Male=sum(CASE WHEN gender_id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
Female=sum(CASE WHEN gender_id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
From MemberAccount
```

This way you sum the number of rows and there's no group by so you get one result.

Comment: Oh that was just a copy-paste from the question, doesn't really matter how many there are.

Comment: Thanks it is really cool..

I gain New knowledge.. and helps me in other sql query tooooo....